I'm trying to write the response into a txt file in python but it's not working

I want to write the response into this text file but for some reason, I can't make that response are coming and I can see that in the terminal window I even created a separate .py file and wrote something into the same file here and it worked but in here it not working***
import requests
import json
import sys

def main():
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        sys.exit()
    response=requests.get("https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=song&limit=50&term=" + sys.argv[1])
    #print(json.dumps(response.json(),indent=2))
    O=response.json()
    with open("songname.txt", "w") as f:
        for result in O["results"]:
            print(result["trackName"])
            #namefile=f"Band_Name_{sys.argv[1]}.txt"
            print(result["trackName"],file=f)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


Show us the exact command you are using to run the python script.

Maybe you have some problems running this since it should be ran with argv?

Please, explain when it does work and when does not (if you were able to run it with some command, share it with us)

Perhaps you're not looking in the correct location for the file?

On a different note, "..." + sys.argv[1] is a security nightmare. The user of your script might add anything which could lead to all manner of bad things happening, locally or on the remote host.

@folengateis Yes it can work, because he's using the file= argument of print().

I executed this script with python <file_path> in the terminal, passing sys.argv[1] (the band or item name) after the file name (sys.argv[0]). The Weezer data retrieval works perfectly, but I noticed that adding names in the terminal prevents the .txt file from opening. This issue is resolved by appending the band name to the link, as shown:```response = requests.get("https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=song&limit=50&term=" + "weezer")


If you want to be able to run the script "as is" (for instance, with unconfigured PyCharm Run), you need to modify it so that it doesn't require any command line arguments to be passed (so that it doesn't use sys.argv). Try this:
import requests

# you can replace "happy" with some other term to try and search that
term = "happy"


def main():
    response = requests.get("https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=song&limit=50&term=" + term).json()
    with open("songname.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        song_names = "\n".join(result["trackName"] for result in response["results"])
        f.write(song_names)
    print(song_names)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

